# ¿Como imprimo listas con objetos?

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando con lista simples, estamos insertando objetos. Pero tengo este código de mostrar lista que solo imprime valores, no se como hago que me imprima objetos.

Este es el `.cpp` de la clase que quiero imprimir:

```
/*
 * Takuilla.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 29/10/2018
 *      Author: Fioxin
 */

#include "Takuilla.h"



void Takuilla::setCantPuestosZona(int cantPuestosZona)
{
    this->cantPuestosZona = cantPuestosZona;
}

int Takuilla::getCantPuestosZona(){
    return cantPuestosZona;
}



void Takuilla::setZona(string zona)
{
    this->zona = zona;
}

string Takuilla::getZona()
{
    return zona;
}

void Takuilla::setPrecio(float precio)
{
    this->precio = precio;
}

float Takuilla::getPrecio()
{
    return precio;
}

string Takuilla::tipoBoleto(int zona){
 string nombre;
 switch(zona){
     case 1: nombre = "Central";
         break;
     case 2:    nombre = "CentralVIP";
         break;
     case 3:    nombre = "Lateral";
         break;
     case 4:    nombre = "Gradas";
         break;
 }
 return nombre;
}

float Takuilla::precioEntrada(int zona){
    float precio;
    switch(zona){
    case 1: // zona Central;
        precio = 800;
        break;
    case 2: // Central VIP
        precio = 1000;
        break;
    case 3: // Lateral
        precio = 500;
        break;
    case 4: // Gradas
        precio = 200;
        break;
    }
    return precio;
}

Takuilla::~Takuilla() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Esta es el `cpp` de la clase lista:

```
#include "Lista.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#include "Lista.h"

template <class Tipo>
nodo<Tipo>* Lista<Tipo>::ObtPrimero(){
  return Primero;
};

template <class Tipo>
void Lista<Tipo>::AsigPrimero(nodo<Tipo>* p){
     Primero=p;
};

template <class Tipo>
Lista<Tipo>::Lista()
{
     Primero=NULL;
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::Vacia()
{
  return Primero == NULL;
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::Llena()
{
  nodo<Tipo> *p;
  p=new nodo<Tipo>;
  if (p==NULL)
     return true;
  else
    {
      delete p;
      return false;
    }
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::InsComienzo(Tipo Valor)
{
  Apuntador nuevo;
  if (!Llena())
     {
      nuevo=new nodo<Tipo>;
      nuevo->info=Valor;
      nuevo->prox=Primero;
      Primero=nuevo;
      return true;
     }
  else
      return false;
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::EliComienzo(Tipo &Valor)
{
  Apuntador viejo;
  if (!Vacia())
     {
      viejo=Primero;
      Valor=viejo->info;
      Primero=Primero->prox;
      delete viejo;
      return true;
     }
  else
      return false;
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::InsDespues(Apuntador p,Tipo Valor)
{
  Apuntador nuevo;
  if (!Llena())
      if (p==NULL)
         return false;
      else
         {
               nuevo=new nodo<Tipo>;
               nuevo->info=Valor;
               nuevo->prox=p->prox;
               p->prox=nuevo;
               return true;
         }
  else
      return false;
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::EliDespues(Apuntador p,Tipo &Valor)
{
  Apuntador viejo;
     if (p==NULL)
         return false;
     else
        if (p->prox==NULL)
           return false;
        else
             {
                   viejo=p->prox;
                   Valor=viejo->info;
                   p->prox=viejo->prox;
                   delete viejo;
                   return true;
             };
};

template <class Tipo>
nodo<Tipo>* Lista<Tipo>::ObtProx(Apuntador p)
{
  return p->prox;
};

template <class Tipo>
void Lista<Tipo>::AsigProx(Apuntador p,Apuntador q)
{
  p->prox=q;
};

template <class Tipo>
Tipo Lista<Tipo>::ObtInfo(Apuntador p)
{
  return p->info;
};

template <class Tipo>
void Lista<Tipo>::AsigInfo(Apuntador p,Tipo Valor)
{
  p->info=Valor;
};

template <class Tipo>
Lista<Tipo>::~Lista()
{
  nodo<Tipo> *p;
  while (!Vacia())
   {
        p=Primero->prox;
        delete Primero;
        Primero=p;
   };
};


/*template <class Tipo>
int Lista<Tipo>::Contar()

{
   int cont=0;
   nodo<Tipo> *ap;
   if(!Vacia())
{
    ap= ObtProx(Primero);
while(ap!=NULL)
{
    ap=ObtProx(ap);
    cont++;
};
    return cont;
}
else
return 0;
}
*/
template <class Tipo>
int Lista<Tipo>::Contar(){
    nodo<Tipo>* p;
    int cont = 0;
    p = Primero;
    while(p != NULL){
        cont++;
        p = p->prox;
    }
    return cont;
}

template <class Tipo>
nodo<Tipo>* Lista<Tipo>::Buscar(Tipo Valor)
{
    nodo<Tipo> *aux =NULL;
    Apuntador ap;
    if(ap!=NULL){
        aux=ap;
        while(aux !=NULL){
            if (aux->info==Valor){
                return aux;
            }
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }

}

template <class Tipo>
void Lista<Tipo>::pasarListaAux(Lista<Tipo> &listaFuente, Lista<Tipo> &listaDestino) {
    Tipo valor;
    int tamano = 0;
    tamano = listaFuente.Contar();
    for(int i = 0; i < tamano; i++){
        listaFuente.EliComienzo(valor);
        listaDestino.InsComienzo(valor);
    }
}

template <class Tipo>
void Lista<Tipo>::mostrarLista(){
  nodo<Tipo> *actual = new nodo<Tipo>;
      actual = Primero;

      while(actual != NULL ){
          cout <<  actual;
          actual = actual->prox;

      }
}
/*
template <class Tipo>
bool Lista<Tipo>::Insertar(Tipo Valor){
    Apuntador ap  = new nodo<Tipo>;


    nodo *aux1= Primero;

    if(!Llena()){
        ap->info=Valor;
        ap->prox=Primero;
        Primero=ap;
    }
    else{
        ap->info=Valor;
        Primero= ap;
        ap->prox=aux1;
    }*/
```

Y aquí el `main`:

```
#include "Lista.cpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Takuilla.h"
#include "Lista.h"
#include "VGeneral.h"

int main(){

    Lista<Takuilla> tk;
    Takuilla Tak;
    VGeneral vg;
    int opc,zona,cantEn,resp;
    float precio;
    string nombreZ,codigo;
    do{

         cout<<"\t ------Bienvenido--- \n";
         cout<<"1. Incluir Takuilla\n";
         cout<<"2. Consultar Takuillas\n";
         cout<<"3. Modificar Takuilla\n";
         cout<<"4. Eliminar Takuilla\n";
         cout<<"5. Salir\n";
         cin>>opc;
         system("cls");

         switch(opc){
         case 1:
             do {
                 if(tk.Llena()){
                     cout<<"\tLista llena. Elimine Elementos para insertar\n";
                 }
             codigo = vg.LeerString("\t Hola Introduzca el codigo de la takuilla\n");
             //buscar el codigo
             zona = vg.LeerNro("Ingrese el tipo de entrada kue vendera \n 1. Central \n 2. Central VIP \n 3. Latera \n 4. Gradas\n");
             precio = Tak.precioEntrada(zona);
             nombreZ = Tak.tipoBoleto(zona);
             cantEn = vg.LeerNro("Cantidad de Entrada kue vendera?");
             Tak.setZona(nombreZ);
             Tak.setPrecio(precio);
             Tak.setCantPuestosZona(cantEn);
             tk.InsComienzo(Tak);
             resp = vg.LeerValidarNro("Desea Agregar otra takuilla? 1.Si 2.No",1,2);
            }while(resp == 1);
             break;

         case 2:
             if(tk.Llena()){
                 cout<<"No hay elementos para mostrar";
             }
             tk.mostrarLista();

             vg.Pausa();
             break;
         case 3:
             break;
         case 4:
             break;
         case 5:
             break;
         }
    }while(opc !=6);
    return 0;
}
```

> Lo que pidió el profesor a imprimir es el listados de todas las
>   taquillas o una lista con todas las taquillas.

Comment: ¿Y en qué consiste exactamente eso de "*Imprimir objetos*"?

Comment: En imprimir los elementos(objetos) que inserte.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver que los objetos estén en una lista?

Comment: No me has entendido. Un objeto, por definición, no puede imprimirse. Un objeto no es más que un conjunto de bytes... ¿es eso lo que quieres imprimir? Yo creo que no. Tu esperas sacar por pantalla una serie de propiedades de los objetos de la lista, ¿cierto? pues entonces eso es exactamente lo que debes detallar en la pregunta: "Cómo es la clase y un ejemplo de la salida esperada". Si además indicas qué es lo que has intentando mejor

Answer (score 0):

## Antes de empezar

Lo primero de todo es que las plantillas son ligeramente distintas a las clases *normales*. Dado que una plantilla es abstracta el compilador, cuando se encuentra con una, **no genera código** ya que ¿Qué código debe generar? ¿Todas las especializaciones posibles? ¿Solo algunas? ¿Y si la plantilla se va a usar con clases que aun no conoce? Demasiadas preguntas sin respuesta.

El caso es que el compilador, cuando se encuentra la declaración de una plantilla, se la apunta en una lista... y no hace nada más con ella hasta que no empieza a encontrarse usos de la misma. En ese momento genera las especializaciones que se necesiten en cada momento.

Debido a esta característica:

- Solo se genera el código mínimo imprescindible... si un método de una clase basada en plantillas no se usa, el mismo no se implementa.
- Si una especialización no se usa, tampoco genera código.
- El compilador necesita **conocer la implementación** de la plantilla en todo momento, si no tendrá problemas para generar el código que corresponda.

El último apartado es el importante y, para no empezar a meter teoría en la respuesta, lo dejaremos en que, en el caso de las plantillas, declaración e implementación deben estar **en el mismo fichero**. Tu estás separando `Lista` en dos archivos y ya te adelanto que eso no te va a funcionar.

## Tu problema

El problema lo tienes porque esperas que una plantilla (que es abstracta) tenga un comportamiento concreto, es decir, que sepa de antemano qué tipo va a contener:

En la función `mostrarLista` no tienes `Takuilla` sino `Tipo`. ¿Y qué información nos da `Tipo`? absolutamente ninguna. No sabemos qué podrá ser y tan pronto puede convertirse en `Takuilla` como en `int` o `void*`... vete tú a saber.

A título personal, no me parece correcto que este método pertenezca a la lista. No me parece correcto porque no creo que haya una única forma de imprimir la lista de elementos (unas veces querrás mostrar más información y otras menos) y esa configuración se complica en exceso metiendo el método en `Lista`.

Por otro lado ignoro si es un requisito del ejercicio, así que vamos a asumir que lo es. Bajo esta premisa, ¿cómo podemos conseguir que `Lista` sepa cómo se imprime el objeto que contiene?

`Lista` es abstracta, así que no <s>podemos</s> debemos llamar a ningún método propio de `Takuilla`. Si lo hacemos nos estamos cargando la plantilla... no funcionará con ningúna clase que no implemente los métodos que utilicemos.

La solución es proporcionarle ese mecanismo desde fuera y una posibilidad es usa una plantilla adicional. Esta plantilla la especializamos para los tipos que necesitemos imprimir. La lista hará uso de estas plantillas para poder imprimir el listado:

#### Lista.h

```
// Implementación por defecto
template<class T>
struct ListTraits
{
  void PrintObject(std::ostream & os, T const& item)
  {
    os << item << '\n';
  }
};

// ...

template <class Tipo>
void Lista<Tipo>::mostrarLista(){
  nodo<Tipo> *actual = Primero;

  ListTraits<Tipo> traits;
  while(actual != NULL ){
    traits.PrintObject(cout,actual->info);
  }
}
```

#### Takuilla.h

```
#include "Lista.h"

class Takuilla
{
  // ...
};

// Especialización para el caso de Takuilla
template<>
struct ListTraits<Takuilla>
{
  void PrintObject(std::ostream & os, Takuilla const& item)
  {
    os << "Zona: " << item.getZona()
       << " - Precio: " << item.getPrecio()
       << '\n';
  }
};
```

Por supuesto en `ListTraits` puedes añadir más información si así lo necesitas.

La gran ventaja de este sistema es que se adaptará automáticamente al tipo de objeto contenido en `Lista`.

Comment: Me da error en algunas cosas. Pero intentare solucionar los errores kue aparecen. Gracias por la respuesta. Es primera vez kue veo un listTraits.

Comment: @XlangnRodriguez Si te da error puede ser porque estés usando un compilador antiguo (como dev-cpp) o por temas de dependencias. Como no has puesto cabeceras no puedo compilar el código

Comment: Por otro lado, el traits no hace nada del otro mundo, de hecho podrías llamar a esa clase como te diese la gana. Es simplemente una plantilla que especializas a tu gusto para configurar el comportamiento de `Lista`